# sum string datatype of a datatable

Tags: c#, .net

I want to compute the sum of a string datatype column in a datatable.

I have already tried this:

```
Int32 omarks = Convert.ToInt32(dt.Compute("Sum(Convert(Marks, 'System.Int32'))", ""));
tbobtained.Text = omarks.ToString();
```

But i'm getting this error:

Syntax Error in Aggregate argument: Expecting a single column argument with a possible child qualifier.

Answer (score 2):

How about this:

```
int omarks = dt.Rows.Select(dr=>(int)dr["Marks"]).Sum();
tbobtained.Text = omarks.ToString();
```

`dr` is the argument of the lambda function that takes a datarow (that's dr) and returns the integer value of the Marks column.

If you want to understand why this code works, you need to freshen up on [LINQ](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb308959.aspx) and [C# lambda expressions](http://www.google.co.il/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cts=1331675168719&ved=0CCsQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Flibrary%2Fbb397687.aspx&ei=HMBfT7iqIuqm0QXPtdSOBw&usg=AFQjCNGV-wHKd7l5lGFu-luKkhX1rKn6pw).

Comment: do i need to use this code in foreach loop? what is dr in this code?

Answer (score 0):

It must not like the nested function calls, even though the [documentation of the expression syntax](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.data.datacolumn.expression.aspx) doesn't mention any issues with that.

I tried extracting the call to `Convert()` into a computed column like this...

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int[] data = new int[] { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };
    DataTable dt = CreateDataTable(data);
    int omarks = Convert.ToInt32(dt.Compute("Sum(MarksInt)", ""));
    string text = omarks.ToString();

    Console.WriteLine(omarks == data.Sum());
}

static DataTable CreateDataTable(IEnumerable<int> data)
{
    DataTable table = new DataTable();

    table.Columns.Add("Marks", typeof(string));
    table.Columns.Add("MarksInt", typeof(int), "Convert(Marks, 'System.Int32')");

    foreach (int i in data)
    {
        DataRow row = table.NewRow();

        row["Marks"] = i.ToString();

        table.Rows.Add(row);
    }

    return table;
}
```

...and it executes without throwing an `Exception` and correctly prints `true`.

Comment: Bacon using your way, I'll have to add an Extra Columns name "MarksInt" in my datatable that doesn't seem the right way to handle this.  i finally had to handle it like this. int omarks = 0;
                    foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
                    {
                        if (dr["Marks"].ToString() != "A")
                        {
                            omarks = omarks + int.Parse(dr["Marks"].ToString());
                        }
                    }
                    tbobtained.Text = omarks.ToString();

Comment: I wasn't proposing this as a real solution, just demonstrating that calling `Convert()` and `Sum()` do work, just not when combined together in one expression for some reason.

Comment: bacon i wanna ask another question from u.. can you plzz give me your email address